# Is it possible to output GPU's video through MOBO

Tags: video, graphics-card, motherboard, vga, amd-ryzen

I have a Ryzen 5 1600 (which does not have an integrated graphics) and a gtx 1060 6GB installed on an Asrock Pro4 AB350m Motherboard.

I was wondering if it is possible to output the GPU's video through the MOBOs video outputs.

Why the question? 
The gtx 1060 (and probably many other newer GPUs) have the video outputs only in digital format. Many old monitors/projectors have only the VGA input (analog) making them unusable with such newer GPUs (the  to VGA adapters wont work - tried already). This kind of monitors/projectors, however, could still be used if attached to the MOBO's VGA or DVI+VGA adapter.

Thanks and best regards =)

Comment: If not, inexpensive HDMI to VGA adapters would solve the issue you face.

Comment: The motherboard's video ports can only be used if you used an AMD APU.